# hvf accelerator for Apple Silicon in guest systems other than aarch64

Tags: macos, qemu

I downloaded QEMU via Homebrew (`brew install qemu`) on a MacBook Pro M2 Pro with MacOS Sonoma. I noticed that the `hvf` accelerator is not compatible with `qemu-system-x86_64`. I also explored other guest systems and the only system that supports `hvf` is `qemu-system-aarch64` (i.e., the same architecture as the host system).

According to [QEMU's documentation](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/introduction.html), MacOS should be able to support `hvf`. Why is this system-dependent? How can I enable `hvf` for the other systems (if possible at all)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hardware acceleration requires that the host CPU and guest CPU are the same architecture -- this is because the guest code is directly running on the host CPU, with no emulation. So on a Mac with Apple Silicon you can run other Arm guests accelerated using `qemu-system-aarch64`; but you can't run accelerated x86 guests, because the host CPU is not an x86. Conversely, on an older intel Mac, you can use `-accel hvf` to run accelerated intel guests with `qemu-system-x86_64`, but you can't run accelerated Arm guests.